# Automatically create business objects from sql database?

Tags: c#-2.0

I was thinking of writing an application that would generate the code for business objects directly from a sql database. It seems like something that would already have been done but maybe I just don't know what to Google for.

Does anyone know if something like this exists?

Comment: This is just **way too broad** to be answered in any meaningful way... you need to be more specific!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, there are many tools that do this. Most fall into the realm of an ORM.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#.NET

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Entity Framework?
They have done an excellent job with object-database mapping